# $http.get error on ng-click function()

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, scope

edit: just to clarify, I've omitted some of the input fields and other code, but included all relevant information.

I have googled and I can't find a solution. I am running a function `userSearch()` on `ng-click` here in my html. The `ng-click` works outside the `form` element but not inside (and by works, I mean the `$http.get` is successful):

partial1.html:

```
<body ng-controller = "userLookUpCtrl">
<form name = "userForm" method = "post" action = "/">
  <input type = "submit" value = "submit" ng-click = "userSearch()">
</form>
</body>
```

The controllers seem to be set up correctly, but from research it seems I may have an issue with my scope. When I move `$http.get('/api/userSearch')` outside the `$scope.userSearch` function, the `$http.get` is successful on page load according to chrome dev tools. If the problem is the scope, then I'm afraid I need someone to spell out for me what exactly I need to do to fix it.

controller.js:

```
  function userLookUpCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.userSearch = function() {
      $http.get('/api/userSearch')             //not successful on ng-click
      .success(function(data) {
        console.log("success" + data);
      })
      .error(function(data){
        console.log("FAILURE!");
      })
    }  
  }
```

express server code:

```
app.get('/api/userSearch', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  User.findOne({username: username}, function(err, username) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    else res.send(username);
  });
});
```

Could it be because I'm trying to `get` at the same time I'm trying to `post` to `/`?

Comment: Have you tried by changing the method from post to get, because the code seems fine by me.

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't seem to make a difference :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you specified an `action` on your form you are trying to both do a full page load via a `POST` to `/` at the same time as trying to do `GET` without a page load. Likely your `GET` is  starting but then being cancelled when the browser does the full page load `POST`.

Comment: Thanks. After removing the post request it worked. Should have tested that my self.